# SQL query from VB.Net to Access database

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I have a query but when I try it's giving me some error on a date or any other variable. I can't get it right. Can you please help me? Here is the code:

```
 Dim tax As Integer = 10
        Dim APPROVED As Boolean = 1
        Dim admin As String = "admin"
        sqlquery.CommandText = "INSERT INTO ACCOUNTS (REFERENCE_NO, ACCT_DATE, ACCT_FROM, ACCT_DUE_DATE, TOTAL, [CURRENCY], AMOUNTS_ARE, TAX, APPROVED, UPDATED_BY, UPDATED_DATE) VALUES ('" & TextBox2.Text & "', #" & DateTimePicker1.Value.Date & "#, '" & TextBox1.Text & "', #" & DateTimePicker2.Value.Date & "#, " & TextBox3.Text & ", '" & ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString & "', '" & ComboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString & "', " & tax & ", '" & APPROVED & "', '" & admin & "', #" & DateTimePicker1.Value.Date & "#);"

        sqlquery.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Now I am getting this error:

> Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

Which date format want to follow?

Comment: Use parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting issues.

Answer (score 1):

Use parameterized queries.

What you have is crazy vulnerable to sql injection attacks. Parameterized queries will fix that issue and your formatting issue:

```vb
Dim tax As Integer = 10
Dim APPROVED As Boolean = 1
Dim admin As String = "admin"
sqlquery.CommandText = "INSERT INTO ACCOUNTS (REFERENCE_NO, ACCT_DATE, ACCT_FROM, ACCT_DUE_DATE, TOTAL, [CURRENCY], AMOUNTS_ARE, TAX, APPROVED, UPDATED_BY, UPDATED_DATE) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"

sqlquery.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarWChar, 10).Value = TextBox2.Text
sqlquery.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.Date).Value = DateTimePicker1.Value.Date 
'...

sqlquery.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Answer (score 0):

Data type mismatch in criteria expression.  You are trying to insert the wrong data-type into your database. Double check your data types in your database. If its a date, insert a date, if it's text, insert text.

Further more, string concatenation make it harder to find errors and it also leaves your open to SQL injection.

Here is a simple example of using parameters:

```
Using con As New OleDbConnection

            con.ConnectionString = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; " & _
                                     "Data Source = " & My.Settings.dbpath
            con.Open()

            Dim sql_insert As String = "INSERT INTO Table_Name (Order_ID, Customer_Name) " & _
                                       "VALUES " & _
                                       "(@entry_ref, @customer_name);"

            Dim sql_insert_entry As New OleDbCommand

            con.Open()

            With sql_insert_entry
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@entry_ref", entry_ref)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@customer_name", tb_new_entry_customer_name.Text.Trim())
                .CommandText = sql_insert
                .Connection = con
                .ExecuteNonQuery()
            End With

            con.close()

End Using
```

As you can see, it's easy to follow and protects your database at the same time.